# Prettier removes escape characters in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, prettier

I am using Prettier in my Angular project, and I'm trying to include a regex pattern for a form validator.  When I run Prettier, the string is fundamentally altered to make the pattern validation dysfunctional, as shown here:

Before:

```
export const EmailVal: ScaffoldValidator = PatternVal(
  "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z_+])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$/"
);
```

After:

```
export const EmailVal: ScaffoldValidator = PatternVal(
  "/^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.w]*[0-9a-zA-Z_+])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-w]*[0-9a-zA-Z].)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$/"
);
```

I've gone through the Prettier Docs, which speaks to changing escapes within the context of single vs double quotes, yet asserts that other escapes will be untouched.  I've also gone through my `tsLint.json`, and nothing stands out to me as the source.  It does denote "Codelyzer" as the ruleset. Is there a setting somewhere I can disable to prevent this behavior?

Comment: I don't think those slashes were *ever* actually in the string. To have an actual backslash, you need to escape it *in the string*: `[-.\\w]`. Or use the proper regex literal form, `/.../`, rather than passing a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use a regex (note: no quotes - just the slashes):

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z_+])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$/;
```

or correct the string escapes (note the double backslashes):

```
"/^[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z_+])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$/";
                  ^^                                 ^^              ^^
```

Consider using EsLint - it can warn you about these cases (see [no-useless-escape rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-escape)):
[image]